# Get a csv file ready for nx.read_edglist?

Tags: python

I have a comma delimited txt file.
Each row can have multiple entries that are then separated by line \n.
Each entry is separated by commas.

So for example,

```
To      From
1,       3
1,       4, 6,
2,       5, 3, 7
```

My end goal is to read this into 
    g = nx.read_edglist(f, create_using) nx.DiGraph(), delimiter =',',nodetype=str

I believe to do this, I need each row to only have 2 entries.

I'd like to know the best way to parse this out into a dataframe.
However, the first column is important and needed. 
I need to not only parse out each entry but I need a new row for them starting with the first entry. So for example with the above data,

I'd need

`1,3
1,4
1,6
2,5
2,3
2,7`

I am trying to use

```
g= f['to'].apply(series, 1).stack()
g.index = g.index.droplevel(-1)
g.name = 'to'
del f['to]
f = f.join(g)
```

But it does not seem to be working....Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry the last line in the code is f = f.join(g)